# What are the Spark transformations that causes a Shuffle?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I have trouble to find in the Spark documentation operations that causes a shuffle and operation that does not. In this list, which ones does cause a shuffle and which ones does not?

Map and filter does not. However, I am not sure with the others.

```
map(func)
filter(func)
flatMap(func)
mapPartitions(func)
mapPartitionsWithIndex(func)
sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed)
union(otherDataset)
intersection(otherDataset)
distinct([numTasks]))
groupByKey([numTasks])
reduceByKey(func, [numTasks])
aggregateByKey(zeroValue)(seqOp, combOp, [numTasks])
sortByKey([ascending], [numTasks])
join(otherDataset, [numTasks])
cogroup(otherDataset, [numTasks])
cartesian(otherDataset)
pipe(command, [envVars])
coalesce(numPartitions)
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is actually extremely easy to find this out, without the documentation. For any of these functions just create an RDD and call to debug string, here is one example you can do the rest on ur own.

```
scala> val a  = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).distinct
scala> a.toDebugString
MappedRDD[5] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
  MapPartitionsRDD[4] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
    **ShuffledRDD[3] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)**
      MapPartitionsRDD[2] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
        MappedRDD[1] at distinct at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
          ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12 (1 partitions)
```

So as you can see `distinct` creates a shuffle. It is also particularly important to find out this way rather than docs because there are situations where a shuffle will be required  or not required for a certain function. For example join usually requires a shuffle but if you join two RDD's that branch from the same RDD spark can sometimes elide the shuffle.

Comment: It's just a generally good point about programming actually - try to answer questions by reading code and using code over reading documentation.  Documentation can often contain duplication of information, and with duplication comes errors and loss of information.  When reading code, one can know *exactly* what is going on :)

Comment: According to the documentation, `toDebugString` returns "A description of this RDD and its recursive dependencies for debugging." So it will include possible shuffles from prior transformations if they exist, even if the most recent transformation does not incur shuffle, right?

Answer (score 25):

Here is a list of operations that *might* cause a shuffle:

[`cogroup`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@cogroup[W1,W2,W3](other1:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W1)],other2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W2)],other3:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W3)],partitioner:org.apache.spark.Partitioner):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(Iterable[V],Iterable[W1],Iterable[W2],Iterable[W3]))])

[`groupWith`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@groupWith[W1,W2,W3](other1:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W1)],other2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W2)],other3:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W3)]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(Iterable[V],Iterable[W1],Iterable[W2],Iterable[W3]))])

[`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@join[W](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W)],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(V,W))]): hash partition

[`leftOuterJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@leftOuterJoin[W](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W)],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(V,Option[W]))]): hash partition

[`rightOuterJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@rightOuterJoin[W](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W)],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(Option[V],W))]): hash partition

[`groupByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@groupByKey():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,Iterable[V])]): hash partition

[`reduceByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]): hash partition

[`combineByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@combineByKey[C](createCombiner:V=%3EC,mergeValue:(C,V)=%3EC,mergeCombiners:(C,C)=%3EC):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,C)]): hash partition

[`sortByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.html#sortByKey(boolean,%20int)): range partition

[`distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@distinct():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

[`intersection`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@intersection(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]): hash partition

[`repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@repartition(numPartitions:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

[`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@coalesce(numPartitions:Int,shuffle:Boolean,partitionCoalescer:Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionCoalescer])(implicitord:Ordering[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

Source: [Big Data Analysis with Spark and Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data/lecture/LQT67/optimizing-with-partitioners), Optimizing with Partitions, Coursera

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be answer but I am not the keeper of answers ;)

Answer (score 5):

This might be helpful:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations

or this:
http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/dev-ops-training, starting with slide 208

from slide 209:
"Transformations that use 'numPartitions' like distinct will probably shuffle"

Answer (score 4):

Here is the generalised statement on shuffling transformations.

> Transformations which can cause a shuffle include **repartition** operations
>   like `repartition` and `coalesce`, **‘ByKey** operations (except for counting)
>   like `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey`, and **join** operations like `cogroup` and
>   `join`.

[source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations)