# What are the Spark transformations that cause a shuffle on Dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read in several places that transformations that include a shuffling stage should be avoided when possible since shuffling involves sending data over the network between the nodes, which can have a high performance cost on a program.

I was looking for a list of Spark transformations that might cause shuffling on Spark's 2.4+ dataframes, and all I came up with is this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273664/what-are-the-spark-transformations-that-causes-a-shuffle) regarding the old RDD API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of transformations from DataFrame API (current version of PySpark 2.4.4 and corresponding functions also in Scala API) which may in general induce a shuffle (but not necessarily, in reality it depends on how your data is prepared (bucketed) or partitioned from some previous transformation):

- `join` (if planned as SortMergeJoin)
- data deduplication using `distinct` / `dropDuplicates`
- aggregation using `groupBy`
- aggregation with window functions using `Window.partitionBy()`
- explicit data repartition using `repartition` / `repartitionByRange` function
- global sorting using `orderBy` / `sort` transformation
- subtracting two dataframes using `subtract`
- counting distinct values in a column using `countDistinct`

Comment: does spark do internal `repartition` as well based on `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` property ? and that cause shuffle(exchange). I have seen exchange in DAG without any from the above list you mention in my code.